# Is attribute node child node of element node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider the following example :

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="03-01.xsl"?>

<ancient_wonders>

    <wonder myattribute = "Green">
        <name language="English">Colossus of Rhodes1</name>
    </wonder>

    <wonder myattribute = "Red">
        <name language="English">Colossus of Rhode2s</name>
    </wonder>

</ancient_wonders>
```

**XSL :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <!-- Output Method -->
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- Root Template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
            <body>

                <p>Output 1 </p>
                <xsl:for-each select="//name//*">
                    <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <p>Output 2</p>
                 <xsl:for-each select="//name/@*">
                    <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <p>Output 3</p>
                 <xsl:for-each select="//name/*">
                    <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(You can see the output [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq66/5) )

Now, we see that `name` have attribute `language`
Now in this case, is `language` node child node of `name` node ?
If yes , why I am not able to see that in the output (link above) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `elem/*` is a short for:

```
elem/child::*
```

which selects all child **elements** of `elem`. Why only elements? Because:

> A node test * is true for any node of the principal node type.

and:

> If an axis can contain elements, then the principal node type is element;

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests

---

Attributes are only available on the `attribute` axis, never on the child axis:

> Each element node has an associated set of attribute nodes; the element is the parent of each of these attribute nodes; however, **an attribute node is not a child of its parent element**.
>    *(emphasis added)*

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#attribute-nodes

---

On the attribute axis, the principal node type is attribute, therefore:

```
elem/attribute::*
```

(which can be shortened to `elem/@*`) selects all attributes of `elem`.

Comment: Can attribute node have parent or child attribute node ?

Comment: An attribute must have a parent element. An attribute cannot have a child node.